# update listbox to recent items c#

Tags: c#, listbox

I have 2 program : a client and a server .

This client will constantly send over data(temp,payload,clientID) every 1 minutes to server . And server will display the data in its listbox .

the problem is , I cannot get my listbox to show the recent data that comes from 
client .

As for now I'm using below in my printMessage method .

```
this.listBox1.Refresh();
```

Below are my full printMessage method :

```
 private void printMessage(string x)
    {
        //listBox1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now + x);
        //return;
        if (x.Trim().Length == 36)
        {
            if (this.listBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                printMessageCallback d = new printMessageCallback(printMessage);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { x });
            }
            else
            {
                this.listBox1.Items.Add("Client ID :" + x);
                this.listBox1.Refresh();
            }
            //sendtoAgent();

        }
        else if (x.Length == 1)
        {
            if (this.listBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                printMessageCallback d = new printMessageCallback(printMessage);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { x });
            }
            else
            {
                this.listBox1.Items.Add("Barrier Payload :" + x);
                this.listBox1.Refresh();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.listBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                printMessageCallback d = new printMessageCallback(printMessage);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { x });
            }
            else
            {
                this.listBox1.Items.Add("" + x);
                this.listBox1.Refresh();
            }

        }

    }
```

Up until now , it doesn't work.

Kindly help.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the ListBox SelectionMode can cause issues when SelectionMode = None.

You could try

```
listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
listBox1.Refresh();
listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.None;
```

Comment: I'm having InvalidOperationException : cross-thread operation was not valid .  Should I put your snippet inside the printMessage() method?Kindly advise .